# Mongoose await not working

Tags: javascript, mongoose, ecmascript-6, async-await

```
async function main() {
  console.log("Start")
  await Author.create({name: 'Some Guy'}, function (err, awesome_instance) {
    console.log("This should be next, but its not")
  });

  console.log("This should be last, but it's not")
}

main()
```

The final log statement is logging before the second.  Why is this the case if I'm using `await`?

Comment: You need to return a promise and you can use `.then` once the promise is resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mongoose methods switch to callback mode when callback is specified, and switch to promise mode when it isn't.

It should be:

```
async function main() {
  try {
    await Author.create({name: 'Some Guy'});
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
  console.log("This should be next, but its not");
  console.log("This should be last, but it's not");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `await` is waiting for `Author.create` to return/resolve. But the first log statement is in a callback and is called asynchronously by `Author.create`, so the `await` does not apply.

If you implement `Author.create` using promises you can use `await`.

Comment: How do I implement with promise?

Comment: You could use a library like mpromise https://www.npmjs.com/package/mpromise

Comment: it seems like just using .then() makes it work?  guessing cus then() returns a promise

Comment: Oh cool, the library you are using probably supports both callbacks and promises